# Building Windows 8 Phone App on Command Line

Tags: command-line, msbuild, batch-file, windows-phone-8

I'm currently porting an existing cross platform framework to Windows Phone 8.

The build process is fully automated and we are using a rock solid CI system.

I can build and deploy Windows Phone 8 samples from Visual Studio (Express 2012),
but now I need to integrate that into our build scripts.

Did anybody ever successfully build (and deploy) a Win Phone 8 app via the commandline?
(Or ant, make, scons, whatever...)

If yes, how?

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I used the following bat file to build WP7 code (+ant automation on top of it). It may be helpful for you.

**build.bat**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe build.xml /t:BuildAndCopy /p:Revision=123
```

where **build.xml** is something like (build itself goes under BuildAll target)

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Major>1</Major>
        <Minor>0</Minor>
        <Build>0</Build>
        <Revision>x</Revision>
        <OutputPath>Build\</OutputPath>
        <OutputPathDebug>..\Build\Debug\</OutputPathDebug>
        <OutputPathRelease>..\Build\</OutputPathRelease>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="Clean; Version">
        <msbuild  Projects="SomeApp.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=$(OutputPathRelease)"/>
        <msbuild  Projects="SomeApp.sln" Properties="Configuration=Debug;OutputPath=$(OutputPathDebug)"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Clean">
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="Exists('$(OutputPath)')"/>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Version">
        <Message Text="Version: $(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"/>
        <XmlUpdate
                Namespace=""
                XmlFileName="WindowsPhone\Properties\WMAppManifest.xml"
                XPath="//App[@Version]//@Version"
                Value="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"/>
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
        <AppFiles Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*.xap"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="BuildAndCopy" DependsOnTargets="BuildAll">
        <Copy
                SourceFiles="@(AppFiles)"
                DestinationFiles="@(AppFiles->'\\fs\Public\projects\mobile\SomeAppWP\$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
                />
        <Copy
                SourceFiles="@(AppFiles)"
                DestinationFiles="@(AppFiles->'\\fs\Public\projects\mobile\SomeAppWP\latest\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
                />
    </Target>


</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks,
this is still using the visual studio (aka msbuild) system to build the project,
but it is displaying all the (sub-)commands that are issued, including their full command line, which is _extremely_ helpful.

Will see how far it gets me.

Answer (score 4):

It should be easy. I'll assume you have the following file structure

$/WP8App/SampleApp.sln

You will have to use the paths and solution file in your project. Execute the following  instructions, and make sure to update solution file and path:

- Open a command prompt
- Execute: `%VS110COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat`
- Execute: `%VS110COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\WPSDK\WP80\vcvarsphoneall.bat`
- Execute: `MSBuild "WP8App/SampleApp.sln" /t:rebuild
  /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"  /v:d`

Please notice:

- The computer where you're going to run these commands should have the development environment for WP8 already set up.
- If your application uses native libraries (such as PlayerFramework http://playerframework.codeplex.com/ which are installed into VS, these libraries should also be installed before running the commands)
- I have used this process on VS2012 Pro and VS2012 Premium and Jenkins as Build Server.

Good luck,
Herb

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sergei's MSBuild.exe hint I was able to build a simple sample via the command line.

https://github.com/AndreasOM/wp8-directx-commandline

There is a build.bat included, which should be enough to get you started to build for "windows phone 8" with the build system of your choice.

It's fairly hacky at the moment,
but once I get the current project done
I will clean it up.

**Hint:**
Never define a "CL" environment variable when working with "CL.exe" ;)

Comment: I don't do WP8 development anymore and don't have a Windows system anymore, so I'm very sorry, but I can't test this anymore :(