# How can i create a windows phone project by using cmd ( command line )?

Tags: command-line, cmd, windows-phone, new-project

How can i create a windows phone project by using cmd ( command line ) ?

Comment: I suspect CMake may be the way you want to go. [Check out this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865700/create-new-visual-studio-project-add-files-and-run-it-command-line)

Comment: Do you mean "create" or do you mean "build/compile"?

Comment: I mean "create" like Creating an Android Project :http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Comment: But, why you need that?

Comment: because i want to create windows phone project from acceleo in eclipse, do you know MDD ?

Comment: If you mean building from the command line, that was previously asked and answered on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020712/building-windows-8-phone-app-on-command-line

Comment: thanks so much, but I want to "create" then i can open and build in visual studio